# allowed_http_origins() only works in theme functions.php

Tags: headers

The following code works in my theme's functions.php file but not in my plugin's main/entry file:

```
/** Allow cross origin resource access
 */
function add_cors_http_header(){
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}
add_action('init','add_cors_http_header');
```

If put into the main plugin file I see this:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/
wptest2/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' 
from origin 'http://localhost:8080' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header 
is present on the requested resource.
```

I need to setup CORS using my plugin files only so users won't have to make custom mods, is there any way to accomplish this?

Also tried in the plugin entry file (and failed):

```
function add_allowed_origins(array $origins = []) {
  $origins[] = 'http://localhost:8080';
  return $origins;
}
add_filter('allowed_http_origins', 'add_allowed_origins');
```

.

```
function add_cors_http_header() {
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}
add_action('send_headers', 'add_cors_http_header');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`send_headers`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/send_headers) action hook instead of `init`. It should work.

```
add_action( 'send_headers', 'add_cors_http_header' );

function add_cors_http_header()
{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, still doesn't work unfortunately. This is after removing the code from the theme's functions.php and copy/pasting your code in the plugin's entry file

Comment: I added the above code to the plugin file and all server responses contain a header with the value I insert. I do not know what may be the cause of other results for you.